# removing wire from through-holes

Tags: soldering

I'm currently attempting to mod my snes jr for rgb output. This requires me to solder some ribbon wire into 4 through holes. I did this once but I (stupidly) made the wire too short and had to remove it using solder wick. I must have done this incorrectly because now the through holes have a few tiny bits of wire in them and I am unable to insert a new wire [image: (see picture)] (I apologize if the picture is low quality it was taken with a cell phone). What soldering/desoldering techniques would one use to clear out these through holes? I have most common soldering tools outside of a desoldering station (I just have a self-heating pump).

Worst case scenario, is there anywhere I could send this to be finished off by someone who's better at soldering? Thanks.

Comment: VGA is 75Ohms impedance so it is best to have tight twisted pair to get low impedance and minimal crosstalk like coax. For this I suggest AWG 30 magnet wire pairs for each RGB signal to a D 15 receptacle for a VGA cable.

Comment: it seems to me that you can do something with a simple iron and a tin sucker: raise the temperature of the iron over +330°C and then heat very quickly the through holes while pushing the sucker on it. Then very quickly suck the tin and the broken copper wires: since the holes seem not overfilled, you should succeed, perhaps trying one or plus times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heat with a soldering iron and use a stainless steel pick or needle with pliers to push through the remains out of the way.

Or add more solder and use a desoldering pump. The extra solder will help bring the wire strands with it.

Answer (score 0):

Apply liquid flux (rosin or no-clean) to the area around the pads and on the pads themselves.  Now apply more solder.  Hold the soldering iron on long enough to ensure that the solder is molten all the way through the circuit board.

Now use tweezers to pull the broken wires out of the holes.  Be very gentle - both with the soldering iron and the tweezers.

Flood the solder joints with solder again, one at a time.  While the solder is molten, sharply rap the circuit board flat against your table.  The solder will fly out of the holes and land on the table.

Inspect the now clean holes.  Repeat the entire procedure for any holes still having wires inside if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use a solder pump not solder sucker. Solder pumps are bigger and have a more powerful suction. 
Add more solder then very quickly remove the soldering iron and place the solder pump over the via and suck it all up.

You can also try adding solder and using pliers or twizers pull the pieces out.

Make sure you do not overheat the vias because you can damege them.